# Finding type signatures of all non-synthetic methods/functions in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scalac, scala-compiler, scala-reflect

I'm trying to find a way to get at the symbol table (?) of the Scala compiler and dump all the type information on the methods/functions in say, a particular SBT project. The current direction I'm going is a compiler plugin, hooking into it right after the `typer` phase.

A bit of wandering around and I'm looking at the root mirror and inspecting the `info.decls` field of it, something along the lines of:

```
def newPhase(prev: Phase): Phase =
  new StdPhase(prev) {
    def apply(unit: CompilationUnit): Unit = {
      val decls = global.RootClass.info.decls
      val scalaz = decls.find(_.toString contains "scalaz")
      println(scalaz.get.info.decls.filter(x => !x.hasMeaninglessName))
```

And it dumps quite a bit of stuff, but.. I still get quite a fair bit of weird output like `class anonfun$reduceUnordered$1 extends ;`

Wondering if I'm going in the right direction at all, and if so what should I be looking more at to *just* get the type signatures of methods in the project?

Answer (score 0):

You are certainly walking the right direction. You can see a full solution in https://github.com/CANVE/extractor. As you have shown, some symbols are "synthetic", such as the case when an anonymous function has been used in the source code. So how much you may want to abstract away those symbols from any "data dump" that you pull out, is up to the specific task you wish to accomplish.